# Looping the whole cells to change a specific formula issue

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a function to change an entire column to new values using a formula, here's the code I'll elaborate more on the idea down there.

The problem is that it hangs and I have to rerun Excel and I'm not sure why.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To Rows.Count
    Cells(i, 4).Formula = "=B" & i & "+6*3600000/86400000+25569"
Next i
End Sub
```

So what's this about? I'm changing the fourth column to excel time because what I have in column B is epoch time, and this is the formula I'm using, it works with my case if I tried one by one, but for some reason it won't work as a whole. I'm not sure what's done wrong? But I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to cells one-by-one is very slow.

Writing formulas one-by-one is slower still, because each must be evaluated before Excel accepts them as formulas.

Doing this a million times can literally freeze Excel.

The solution is to write them all in one shot (no loops):

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    [d2:d1048576] = "=B2+6*3600000/86400000+25569"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

' Another way of doing mass calculation is by using copy and paste method.
It will be better to convert the columns into values so that the sheet won't calculate again and again. It helps to prevent the sheet from hanging issues

```
Sub Button2_Click()

    Range("D2").Formula = "=b1" & "+6*3600000/86400000+25569"

    Range("D2").Copy
    Range("D2:d1048576").PasteSpecial xlValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("D:D").Value = Range("D:D").Value

    End Sub
```

Comment: Your premise is not necessarily true. In addition you should avoid utilizing the user's clipboard. And, there is no point to your last line of code.

Comment: No noticeable difference in time.

Comment: I am not getting the reason by the person who downvote my answer, Is there should be only one answer for a question. I am just giving alternate answer to the question

Comment: @ExcelHero I have provided a safe method in order to avoid the file from getting hanged .Thanks for your comments.

Comment: It's not efficient. Even OP has told you. Using the user's clipboard for no compelling reason and without the user's permission is poor form. Your last line does nothing in your code since you have already pasted values. So, to recap, your solution is inefficient and ineffective and inappropriate.